Let $F\left( {x,y}\right) = 0$ be a $8$ like smooth curve in $\Bbb R^2$, how many points satify $F_x=F_y= 0$?

Let $F\left( {x,y}\right)  = 0$ be a $8$ like smooth curve in $\Bbb R^2$, at least how many points satify $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = 0$?

Using $F=[(x-1)^2+y^2][(x+1)^2+y^2]$, we see $3$ points should satify.
So how to argue for general $F$? the higest, the lowest, and the cross one?

In general, we expect $1$. I don’t know what you really mean by “8-like smooth.” Your equation defines a tacnode, not a figure 8.

To me a smooth plane curve means that $F$, $\partial F/\partial x$ and $\partial F/\partial y$ NEVER vanish at the same point. Admittedly "8 like" and "smooth" is already a contradiction.

The solutions of $F(x, y) =[(x-1)^2+y^2][(x+1)^2+y^2] = 0$ are just two points. Perhaps you meant $F(x, y) =[(x-1)^2+y^2][(x+1)^2+y^2] - 1$? And what are the three points with $F_x = F_y = 0$ for that curve?

According to my assumption, i think that the F(x) may be  lemniscate of Huygens or Lemniscate of Gerono i.e x^4= a2(x^2 – y^2) which resembles a 8 type of figure. It has F(X)=0 at 3 points and F(y) at 1 point...
